# Should we remove WSOiN links from answers/questions on main sites?

Tags: discussion, clean-up, broken-link

**Edit:** *bfavaretto* pointed out that these links are very important context on **meta sites**, I drastically edit this question to exclude them.

Should we start a manual cleanup of the broken links of "What StackOverflow is not?" (a.k.a WSOiN) in answers and questions on **main sites**?

Here [is a query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%22*/128548*%22) that shows 18 results, the only purpose of linking to WSOiN outside meta was only meant to harm

Comment: I used plural in "sites" thinking it was used across all SE sites, but I think it was only a SO thing... If someone can confirm this I think will make an edit then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WSOiN links on Meta**

No, it's important for discussions either about WSOiN, or mentioning it as a source, and essential context for many of them. I think all links to WSOiN **on Meta** should be kept. Remember 10k Meta users can still see the post.

**WSOiN links on Stack Overflow**

The main concern for deleting WSOiN was the way it was being used in comments. I guess the link cleanup by the time the post was deleted only targeted comments.

I went through some of the [questions on SO that still link to it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2Ameta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F128548%2Fwhat-stack-overflow-is-not%2F%2A%22), and I think yes, we should do something about them. I can't think of a case where such links would be apropriate outside of comments on SO, even when WSOiN was alive.

Here are some examples of what I saw, and the actions I already took:

- [Clearly not an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10272248/825789), and I flagged it as such.
- [First two sentences were noise anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10261044/825789), so I edited those sentences out and got rid of the link.
- [Just removed the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10505525/825789).
- [Clearly not an answer again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10937131/825789), flagged.
- [Should be a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11117542/825789), flagged.

Comment: How is it essential context to that particular question? Not being able to see WSOiN myself, I can still understand the question perfectly fine without it.

Comment: I forgot I was on meta, as soon as I saw the link, my question rised... But upon further search, it seems there are 14 answers/questions [on the main site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*meta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F128548%2Fwhat-stack-overflow-is-not%2F*%22). Do you think it would be abusive to edit my original question to exclude meta and make your answer useless?

Comment: @Bart You're right, I edited my answer. However my point is the same.

Comment: @ajax333221 No problem, go ahead! :)